# how to get iamge from diffrent data api in flutter like this

Tags: json, flutter, carousel-slider

I have my model for json, service to get api
I just dont know how to get image like this [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8B45.png)
from this json [from this](https://run.mocky.io/v3/654bd15e-b121-49ba-a588-960956b15175)
the Ipone Mega is the carousel slider(4 images in json link), below the other is just column
if you could show it in carousel Slider i will be very grateful to you

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_work/apiService/fetch_data.dart';
import 'package:my_work/apiService/phone.dart';


class CarouselSliderData extends StatefulWidget{
  const CarouselSliderData({super.key});


  @override
  State<CarouselSliderData> createState() => CarouselSliderDataState();
}

class CarouselSliderDataState extends State<CarouselSliderData> {
  Phone? info;
   @override
  void initState() {
       DioService.getDataMocky(
           url:'https://run.mocky.io/v3/654bd15e-b121-49ba-a588-960956b15175'
       ).then((value) async {
         if(value != null){
           setState((){
             info = value!;
           });
         }
       }).catchError(
             (value) => (value),
       );

    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Image(image:)
                ],
              );



       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** get the json from API. I call this variable is

> Map<String, dynamic> json;

**Step 2:** As you can see, `"home_store"` of your json is a list of phones. Therefore, you create a model class called `PhoneModel` like this:

```
class PhoneModel {
  int id;
  bool isNew;
  String title;
  String subtitle;
  String picture;
  bool isBuy;

  /// constructor
  PhoneModel({this.id ...});

  /// from json to class model
  PhoneModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    this.id = json["id"];
    this.isNew = json["is_new"];
    ...
  }
}
```

Then do like this to catch the list of items:

```
List<PhoneModel> listPhones =  List<PhoneModel>.from(
  (json['home_store'] as List).map((e) => PhoneModel.fromJson(e)),
);
```

Now your list of phone is variable `listPhones`. Url is field `picture`. Do `Image.network` or anythings else... Good luck!

Comment: Thanks my friend. In the evening i will try. Thank you